# MongoDB unwind only first item

Tags: mongodb

I have Mongo 3.2 database with collection of conversations. Each element looks like that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("582e9f85160238a44ef0bfbd"),
"conversation_id" : 39,
"owner_id" : 8,
"title" : "Title",
"recipients" : 1,
"last_modified" : "2016-10-28 06:21:35",
"locked" : 0,
"recipients_details" : [ 
    {
        "user_id" : 1,
        "last_message" : "2016-10-28 06:21:35"
    }, 
    {
        "user_id" : 8,
        "last_message" : "2016-10-28 06:14:00"
    }
]
}
```

I wanna get all users who posted last message in conversations which contains some **user_id**. As example, if I want to get all conversations of user #8, in the JSON above 'recipients_details' should contain only 1 record with user_id = 1, because his message was last. I've tried this code, but it gives all records and unwinding it is not a solution (in this statement):

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {$match:{'recipients_details.user_id':1}},
  {$sort:{'last_modified':-1}},
  {$project:{_id:1,last_modified:1,recipients_details:1}}
])
```

**UPD**: Structure was migrated from 2 MySQL tables (conversations and recipients(`conversation_id`,`user_id`,`message_posted`)). I want to find analog of this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `recipients` WHERE `conversation_id` IN (SELECT `conversation_id` FROM `recipients` WHERE `user_id` = 1) AND `user_id` <> 1 GROUP BY `conversation_id` ORDER BY `message_posted` DESC
```

And as result I've got:

```
         conversation_id  user_id  message_posted       
         ---------------  -------  ---------------------
         40      164  2016-11-01 12:13:23  
         39        8  2016-10-28 06:14:00  
         27       65  2016-10-26 14:26:59  
         23       65  2016-10-26 14:23:59  
         24       62  2016-10-26 08:44:14  
         20       62  (NULL)               
         25       76  (NULL)               
         42       64  (NULL)               
         43       65  (NULL)               
         44       68  (NULL)
```

Comment: IIUC last is max `last_message` right?

Comment: If I get this correctly, do you want to find the set of users who post the last message in a conversation (sorted on `last_message`) belong to a certain `user_id`? If this is the case, why are you matching on `{'recipients_details.user_id':1}`

Comment: It was just for example. Here is a [paste](http://pastebin.com/F6ZCErAU) of what I have and what I ecpect. Just want to find last user who posted to conversations, but not for all of them, just for current user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking your raw data it seems like you first find out those documents which contains `recipients_details.user_id:8` and after that in `recipients_details` array you want to sort out `last_message` values and get only first values. So for this you should used mongo array set operations for this I used [$setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) so first I filter matched users_id and then used set difference to get only difference of array and last unwind result for sort data and grouped all results. Check below query :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$match": {
    "recipients_details.user_id": {
        "$in": [8]
    }
    }
}, {
    "$project": {
    "filter": {
        "$setDifference": ["$recipients_details", {
            "$filter": {
                "input": "$recipients_details",
                "as": "recp",
                "cond": {
                    "$eq": ["$$recp.user_id", 8]
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    "conversation_id": 1,
    "owner_id": 1,
    "title": 1,
    "recipients": 1,
    "last_modified": 1,
    "locked": 1
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$filter"
}, {
    "$sort": {
    "filter.last_message": -1
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "conversation_id": {
        "$first": "$conversation_id"
    },
    "owner_id": {
        "$first": "$owner_id"
    },
    "title": {
        "$first": "$title"
    },
    "recipients": {
        "$first": "$recipients"
    },
    "last_modified": {
        "$first": "$last_modified"
    },
    "locked": {
        "$first": "$locked"
    },
    "recipients_details": {
        "$first": {
            "user_id": "$filter.user_id",
            "last_message": "$filter.last_message"
        }
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: If I will try to replace user_id for user #8 as result I'll get recipient_details for him aswell instead of user #1 expected. {"_id":ObjectId("582e9f85160238a44ef0bfbd"),"recipients_details":[{"user_id":8,"last_message":"2016-10-28 06:14:00"}]}

Comment: did not understand can you explain more or as per @hyades comment do you want to find out only `last_message` sorted data then why you matched it with `user_id` ?

Comment: That is the result what I expect: 1. Find conversations where user #8 in "recipients_details". 2. Remove user #8 from retrieved data. 3. In "recipients_details" left only 1 user who posted last message (any user if everyone's las_message is null)

Comment: What happened if there was more than two users in `recipients_details` ?

Comment: Each element has the same structure. Looks [this paste](http://pastebin.com/F6ZCErAU) of what I have and what I expect for.

Comment: Yep. That is exaclty what I mean. Btw, I'm 1 step behind on less complex solution. I realized, that in aggregation you could do any query you want in any order, so I've made this one: `db.conversations.aggregate([
    {$match:{'recipients_details.user_id':1}},
    {$unwind:'$recipients_details'},
    {$sort:{'last_modified':-1, 'recipients_details.last_message':-1}},
    {$match:{'recipients_details.user_id':{$ne:1}}},
    {$project:{_id:1,last_modified:1,recipients_details:1}}
])` and now result should be grouped and it's done too.

Comment: Here's my final version of doing (as I think) the same: `db.conversations.aggregate([
    {$match:{'recipients_details.user_id':1}},
    {$unwind:'$recipients_details'},
    {$sort:{'last_modified':-1, 'recipients_details.last_message':-1}},
    {$match:{'recipients_details.user_id':{$ne:1}}},
    {$group:{"_id":"$_id"
    ,"owner_id":{"$first":"$owner_id"}
    ,"title":{"$first":"$title"}
    ,"last_modified":{"$first":"$last_modified"}
    ,"user_id":{"$first":"$recipients_details.user_id"}
    ,"last_message":{"$first":"$recipients_details.last_message"}
    }}
])`